# Select TOP X Rows with Parameter in SSRS Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm wanting to allow users to select how many rows of data to display in a  line graph created in Report Builder. The query works fine when I run it in the Dataset, however, when I run the output in ReportBuilder, I receive the following error message:

> An error has occurred during report processing. For more information about this error navigate to the report serve on the local server machine or enable remote error.

```
SELECT TOP(@ReturnCount)

LOAN.OPEN_DATE,

SUM(LOAN.ORIG_AMT),
COUNT(OPEN_DATE) AS Posted_Date_Count
FROM PREBOOKLOAN AS PBL
INNER JOIN 
    MEMBERSHIPPARTICIPANT AS MP ON PBL.MEMBER_NBR = MP.MEMBER_NBR AND PARTICIPATION_TYPE = 101
INNER JOIN
    INDIVIDUAL AS I on MP.INDIVIDUAL_ID = I.INDIVIDUAL_ID
INNER JOIN
    PREBOOKLOANPRODUCT AS PBLP on PBL.LPTCODE = PBLP.LPTCODE

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    LOAN on PBL.APLNUM = LOAN.LOAN_NOTE_NBR AND LOAN.OPEN_DATE >= '07/01/20' AND LOAN.OPEN_DATE <= '12/31/2020'

WHERE PBL.DATE_STARTED >= '07/01/2020' AND PBL.DATE_STARTED <= '12/31/2020'

AND
Loan.Loan_Type = 61
GROUP BY LOAN.OPEN_DATE
```

I also tried using OFFSET in SQL, which worked in the query, but not when viewing the report. As a test, I deleted my chart and replaced it with a table to see if that would work, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well what was the actual error?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to it and the person who does will be gone for a few days due to a sickness in his family.

Comment: So it doesn't give an error when you run it in your report designer?

Comment: Not on the design tab. It does when I select Run, but only after entering a number in the parameter, say 10.

Comment: OK so, what error does it show in the output pane when you do that?

Comment: Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1' (rsErrorExecutingCommand)

Comment: There must be more information there somewhere.

Comment: I just built a quick report using `top(@NumRows)` and it worked fine. Maybe check that your parameter is actually an integer?

Comment: So I checked and it wasn't, even though I originally set it to integer. I change it back, run the report, get an error, go back to the parameter and it set to text again. Not sure what's causing it, but I at least know that's the issue now. I will start over, copy the code and see if it does it in the new rbl file. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the available information, you may want to check your parameter settings within SharePoint itself and ensure the correct data type is assigned to your parameter.

To do this:

1. Open the SharePoint folder containing your report.
2. Click the ellipses (...) next to your report name.
3. Click the ellipses next to `Share` (bottom right of pop-up window)
4. Click `Manage Parameters`
5. Your parameters should display with the assigned Data Type. Check here and ensure the data types are aligned with your expected parameter input for your report.

Hope this helps!